# Triple Fault после включения пейджинга

Tags: c++, gcc, kernel, paging, osdev

Пытаюсь создать свою маленькую ОС, но возникла большая проблема, которую мне пока что не удалось решить - пейджинг. Не получается загрузить директорию страниц в регистр **CR3**, сразу же происходит *Triple Fault*, в **CR0** после этого находится значение **0x60000010**. Ядро располагается после 16 MB(**0x1000000**). Код(для теста, поэтому такой простой):

```cpp
puint32_t PageDirectory = (puint32_t)0x1004000;
puint32_t PageTable = (puint32_t)0x1005000;
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 1024; i++) PageDirectory[i] = 0x00000002;//Present
for (uint32_t i = 0x1000; i < 0x1400; i++) PageTable[i] = (i * 0x1000) | 3;
PageDirectory[0] = (uint32_t)PageTable | 3;
asm(
    "movl %0, %%cr3;"
    "movl %%cr0, %%eax;"
    "orl $0x80000000, %%eax;"
    "movl %%eax, %%cr0"::"r"(PageDirectory));
```

**EDIT1**: Вынес код в paging.asm:

```
[Bits 32]
[Global PagingLoadDirectory]
[Global PagingEnable]

PagingLoadDirectory:
    mov eax, [esp+8]
    mov cr3, eax
    ret

PagingEnable:
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x80000000
    mov cr0, eax
    ret
```

Переписал загрузку пейджинга следующим образом:

```cpp
extern "C" void PagingLoadDirectory(psize_t paging_directory);
extern "C" void PagingEnable();
psize_t PageDirectory = (psize_t)0x1004000;
psize_t PageTable = (psize_t)0x1005000;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 1024; i++) PageDirectory[i] = 0x00000002;
for (size_t i = 0x1000; i < 0x1400; i++) PageTable[i] = (i * 0x1000) | 3;
PageDirectory[0] = (size_t)PageTable | 3;
PagingLoadDirectory(PageDirectory);
PagingEnable(); //Именно при вызове этой функции возникает Triple Fault
```

**EDIT2**: Переписал загрузку пейджинга, оказалось, что таблицы не были размечены нужным образом, всё работает, однако пейджинг 1 к 1, буду думать, как записать только страницу с ядром на другой адрес(в данный момент распределил 5 страниц):

```cpp
psize_t PageDirectory = (psize_t)0x1200000;
psize_t PageTable = (psize_t)0x1300000;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 0x400; i++) PageDirectory[i] = 2; //Заполняю всю директорию "неактивными"(без флага Present) таблицами, т.к. не буду размещать все таблицы
for (size_t i = 0; i < 0x400*5; i++) PageTable[i] = (i * 0x1000) | 3; //Заполняю 5 каталогов страниц, начиная с адреса *0x00000000*, заканчивая *0x1400000*
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) PageDirectory[i] = ((size_t)PageTable + i * 0x1000) | 3; //Наконец, помещаю размещённые таблицы страниц в директорию
PagingLoadDirectory(PageDirectory);
PagingEnable(); //Profit!
```

Comment: `PageTable` - это указатель. зачем вы его переделываете на число? `= (uint32_t)PageTable | 3;`

Comment: Не стоит использовать ассемблерные вставки, делайте код на ассемблере отдельно.

Comment: AlexGlebe, в PageDirectory должны храниться адреса, выровненные по границе (в данном случае 0x1000), в которых есть флаги, `| 3` как раз добавляет такие флаги: RW, Present

Comment: "В защищёном режиме работа с регистрами управления позволена только программам с нулевым уровнем привилегий." это по поводу регистров cr0 , cr3. У вас точно полный доступ?

Comment: AlexGlebe, да, полный

Comment: Возможно, как сказал  user7860670, дело в ассемблерных вставках, перепишу код, расскажу, помогло ли

Comment: @user7860670, не помогло, всё-равно Triple Fault

Comment: В х86 c MMU никогда дело не имел, но предполагаю, что у вас какая-то ошибка в структуре таблиц трансляции верхнего уровня.  (RTFM)

Comment: @avp, похоже на то